# Can i run IIS and Node.JS simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, iis

Actually i have a server where there is hosted a website written in `ASPX` so it use `IIS` to run.

Now i would add an `API` that will permise to add some data to server database, the API is written in `Node.JS` so i was wondering if it's possible to run simultaneously Node and IIS.

Node is listening on port 3000 and obviously if i simply try to run '`websitedomain.it:3000/data`' it doesn't work..

If something like this is possible how could i implement it?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you could run IIS and Node.JS simultaneously.

When you host webform website in IIS, it will not prevent node.js application being accessed.

You could self-host your node.js application then use URL rewrite rule and ARR to rewrite websitedomain.it:3000/data to your node.js api.

https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Of course, you could host your nodejs application in IIS with iisnode extension directly.
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases